# CloudSQL SQLAdmin API - Unexpected Authentication Exception

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm just starting with Cloud SQL Management API, setup an API Key, and followed instructions as per the docs at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#finding-information-about-the-apis.

Relevant code:

```
       public GoogleDatabaseApi(IRedisClientsManager redisManager, IDb connection)
        {
            this.redisManager = redisManager;
            this.connection = connection;
            this.service = new SQLAdminService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "cli",
                ApiKey = "AIz ...WRXJU",
                GZipEnabled = true
            });
        }

        internal async Task SyncDbServersAndDatabasesAsync()
        {
            var res = await service.Instances.List(ProjectName).ExecuteAsync();
```

And I receive the following exception on the last line above..

```
Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [401]

Errors [
    Message[Login Required.] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]
```

I've setup the API Key in the Cloud Console for the same project, and its currently unrestricted (yellow warning triange.)
[image: Cloud Console with credentials]

I can see that the usage is incrementing.

I believe that API Key is the appropriate mechansism for my use case. And as I'm passing in a legitimate API Key, I don't understand why I'd be seeing an exception referencing OAuth2.

> 1. Simple API access (API keys)
>
> These API calls do not access any private user data. Your application must authenticate itself as an application belonging to your Google API Console project. This is needed to measure project usage for accounting purposes.
>
> API key: To authenticate your application, use an API key for your API Console project. Every simple access call your application makes must include this key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't fully the docs.

**API Key** is a form of authorisation, not authentication.

So either **OAuth V2** or a **service account** credentials set is required.

Solution to get something working was:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("credentials.json");

this.service = new SQLAdminService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "cli",
                ApiKey = "AIz....JU",
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                GZipEnabled = true,
            });
```

And depending on the service account in use, the API Key isn't necessary.